# Color in css files

Tags: phpstorm

Before, for example, in PhpStorm 9 I could see the css color preview icon in gutter:

[image]

Now in PhpStorm 2016.1 I can not see this feature

[image]

Even I have activated:

[image]

How I can make it work again in PhpStorm?

This is my Phpstorm version:

[image]

Comment: What is your IDE version exactly (including build number)?

Comment: @LazyOne answer updated.

Comment: You mean "question" :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a bug in PhpStorm v2016.1 final.

It's now [fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151485) -- but you have to use **2016.1.1** EAP build or wait until 2016.1.1 will actually be released.

2016.1.1 EAP (latest for this moment build) can be downloaded [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/04/phpstorm-2016-1-1-eap-145-969/).

---

If for some reason you do not want to use EAP build .. you can play with editor font size (try increasing or decreasing it a bit) -- somehow they are related (that's the actual reason for the bug).